# Desktop Version Quickbooks integration with Windows service

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

I want to integrate quickbooks with my windows service. Currently I am using quickbooks SDK. Its working with windows application. In windows service it shows "Could not start QuickBooks." Exception.

How to solve this issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QuickBooks does not support applications running as a Windows Service. The application needs to be running in the context of a user.

Ref: https://help.developer.intuit.com/s/article/Troubleshooting-Could-not-start-QuickBooks

Comment: Is it possible with quickbooks web connector, that is when i add the details in quickbooks it should add in my db? without a windows service?